# TradingView Pine Script with alerts that don't fire

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

On my chart I have a visual representation of a condition that becomes true and then plots an arrow, in the block of code that this condition becomes true I have an alert set up. When the condition becomes true and I see the visual confirmation the alert doesn't fire... Any ideas please?

Please see alertcondition right at the bottom, shortbool and longbool might not be working out in this part of the code

```
//@version=5

indicator("X48 - Indicator | Midnight Hunter | V.1.6", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500, max_labels_count = 500,max_boxes_count = 500)

//INPUTS
var GRP1 = "== Midnight Hunter Band Setting =="
HalfLength = input.int(56, "Centered TMA Half Period", group = GRP1)
string PriceType = input.string("Weighted", "Price to use", options = ["Close", "Open", "High", "Low", "Median", "Typical", "Weighted", "Average"], group = GRP1)
AtrPeriod = input.int(110, "Average true range period", group = GRP1)
AtrMultiplier = input.float(2.5, "Average true range multiplier", group = GRP1)
TMAangle = input.int(4, "Centered TMA angle caution", group = GRP1)
tmawidth = input.int(defval = 1, title = 'Band LineWidth', minval = 1, maxval = 4, group = GRP1)

//Gold Hunter Setting : 56 , 110 , 2.5 , 4

//VARIABLES
float tmac = na
float tmau = na
float tmad = na

var float pastTmac = na //from the previous candle
var float pastTmau = na
var float pastTmad = na

float tmau_temp = na //before looping
float tmac_temp = na
float tmad_temp = na

float point = syminfo.pointvalue //NEEDS MORE TESTS

bool last = false //checks if a loop is needed
bool longbool = false
bool shortbool = false
bool longflagbool = false
bool shortflagbool = false
var string alertSignal = "EMPTY" //needed for alarms to avoid repetition

//COLORS
var GRP2 = "== Midnight Colors =="
var color colorBuffer = na
color colorDOWN = input.color(color.new(color.red, 0), "Bear Color", inline = "5", group = GRP1)
color colorUP = input.color(color.new(color.green, 0), "Bull Color", inline = "5", group = GRP1)
color colorBands = input.color(color.new(#b2b5be, 0), "3 Bands Color", inline = "5", group = GRP1)
bool cautionInput = input.bool(false, "Caution Label", inline = "6", group = GRP1)

//ALERTS
var GRP3 = "Alerts (Needs to create alert manually after every change)"
bool crossUpInput = input.bool(false, "Crossing up", inline = "7", group = GRP3)
bool crossDownInput = input.bool(false, "Crossing down", inline = "7", group = GRP3)
bool comingBackInput = input.bool(false, "Coming back", inline = "7", group = GRP3)
bool onArrowDownInput = input.bool(false, "On arrow down", inline = "8", group = GRP3)
bool onArrowUpInput = input.bool(false, "On arrow up", inline = "8", group = GRP3)

//CLEAR LINES
a_allLines = line.all
if array.size(a_allLines) > 0
    for p = 0 to array.size(a_allLines) - 1
        line.delete(array.get(a_allLines, p))
        
//GET PRICE        
Price(x) =>
    float price = switch PriceType
        "Close" => close[x]
        "Open" => open[x]
        "High" => high[x]
        "Low" => low[x]
        "Median" => (high[x] + low[x]) / 2
        "Typical" => (high[x] + low[x] + close[x]) / 3
        "Weighted" => (high[x] + low[x] + close[x] + close[x]) / 4
        "Average" => (high[x] + low[x] + close[x] + open[x])/ 4
    price

//MAIN
for i = HalfLength to 0

    //ATR
    atr = 0.0
    for j = 0 to  AtrPeriod - 1
        atr += math.max(high[i + j + 10], close[i + j + 11]) - math.min(low[i + j + 10], close[i + j + 11])
    atr /= AtrPeriod
    
    //BANDS
    sum = (HalfLength + 1) * Price(i)
    sumw = (HalfLength + 1)
    k = HalfLength
    for j = 1 to HalfLength
        sum += k * Price(i + j)
        sumw += k
        if (j <= i)
            sum  += k * Price(i - j)
            sumw += k
        k -= 1
    tmac := sum/sumw
    tmau := tmac+AtrMultiplier*atr
    tmad := tmac-AtrMultiplier*atr
    
    //ALERTS
    if i == 0 //Only on a real candle 
        if (high > tmau and alertSignal != "UP") //crossing up band
            if crossUpInput == true //checks if activated
                alert("Crossing up Band") //calling alert
            alertSignal := "UP" //to avoid repeating 
        else if (low < tmad and alertSignal != "DOWN") //crossing down band
            if crossDownInput == true
                alert("Crossing down Band")
            alertSignal := "DOWN"
        else if (alertSignal == "DOWN" and high >= tmad and alertSignal != "EMPTY") //back from the down band
            if comingBackInput == true
                alert("Coming back")
            alertSignal := "EMPTY"
        else if (alertSignal == "UP" and low <= tmau and alertSignal != "EMPTY") //back from the up band
            if comingBackInput == true
                alert("Coming back")
            alertSignal := "EMPTY"
            
    //CHANGE TREND COLOR
    if pastTmac != 0.0
        if tmac > pastTmac
            colorBuffer := colorUP
        if tmac < pastTmac
            colorBuffer := colorDOWN
            
    //SIGNALS
    reboundD = 0.0
    reboundU = 0.0
    caution = 0.0
    if pastTmac != 0.0
        if (high[i + 1] > pastTmau and close[i + 1] > open[i + 1] and close[i] < open[i])
            reboundD := high[i] + AtrMultiplier * atr / 2
            if (tmac - pastTmac > TMAangle * point)
                caution := reboundD + 10 * point
        if (low[i + 1] < pastTmad and close[i + 1] < open[i + 1] and close[i] > open[i])
            reboundU := low[i] - AtrMultiplier * atr / 2
            if (pastTmac - tmac > TMAangle * point)
                caution := reboundU - 10 * point
    
    //LAST REAL
    if barstate.islast and i == HalfLength
        last := true
        tmau_temp := tmau
        tmac_temp := tmac
        tmad_temp := tmad
        
    //DRAW HANDICAPPED BANDS
    if barstate.islast and i < HalfLength
        line.new(bar_index - (i + 1), pastTmau, bar_index - (i), tmau, width = 2, style = line.style_dotted, color = colorBands)
        line.new(bar_index - (i + 1), pastTmac, bar_index - (i), tmac, width = 2, style = line.style_dotted, color = colorBuffer)
        line.new(bar_index - (i + 1), pastTmad, bar_index - (i), tmad, width = 2, style = line.style_dotted, color = colorBands)
        
    //DRAW SIGNALS
    if reboundD != 0
        //label.new(bar_index - (i), reboundD, color = colorDOWN, style = label.style_triangledown, size = size.tiny, textcolor = na)
        label.new(bar_index - (i), reboundD, '▼', color = na, textcolor = colorDOWN, textalign=  text.align_center)
        shortbool = true
        if i == 0 and onArrowDownInput == true //alert
            alert("Down arrow") 
        if caution != 0 and cautionInput == true
            label.new(bar_index - (i), reboundD, color = colorUP, style = label.style_xcross, size = size.tiny, textcolor = na)
    if reboundU != 0
        //label.new(bar_index - (i), reboundU, color = colorUP, style = label.style_triangleup, size = size.tiny, textcolor = na)
        label.new(bar_index - (i), reboundU, '▲', color = na, textcolor = colorUP, textalign = text.align_center)
        longbool = true
        if i == 0 and onArrowUpInput == true //alert
            alert("UP arrow") 
        if caution != 0 and cautionInput == true
            label.new(bar_index - (i), reboundU, color = colorDOWN, style = label.style_xcross, size = size.tiny, textcolor = na)
            
    //SAVE HISTORY
    pastTmac := tmac
    pastTmau := tmau
    pastTmad := tmad
    
    //LOOP IS ONLY FOR HANDICAPPED
    if barstate.islast != true
        break

//DRAW REAL BANDS
plot(last ? tmau_temp : tmau, title = "TMA Up", color = colorBands, linewidth=tmawidth, style = plot.style_line, offset = -HalfLength)
plot(last ? tmac_temp : tmac, title = "TMA Mid", color = colorBuffer, linewidth=tmawidth, style = plot.style_line, offset = -HalfLength)
plot(last ? tmad_temp : tmad, title = "TMA Down", color = colorBands, linewidth=tmawidth, style = plot.style_line, offset = -HalfLength)

threeengulfing_mode = input.bool(title="3 Candle Engulfing Signal", defval=true, group="== ENGULFING SIGNAL ==", inline = '9')
engulfing_mode = input.bool(title="Normal Engulfing Signal", defval=false, group="== ENGULFING SIGNAL ==", inline = '9')

// bullish engulfing (Bueng)
Bueng = open[3] > close[3] and open[2] > close[2] and open[1] > close[1] and close > open and (close >= open[1] or close[1] >= open) and close - open > open[1] - close[1]
plotshape(threeengulfing_mode ? Bueng : na, style=shape.flag, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(#00e926,0), size=size.small, textcolor = color.new(#4eff64,0))

// bearish engulfing (Beeng)
Beeng = open[3] < close[3] and open[2] < close[2] and close[1] > open[1] and open > close and (open >= close[1] or open[1] >= close) and open - close > close[1] - open[1]
plotshape(threeengulfing_mode ? Beeng : na, style=shape.flag, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(#ff571b,0), size=size.small, textcolor = color.new(#ff5a9b,0))
// bullish engulfing (Bueng)
Bueng2 = open[3] > close[3] ? open[2] > close[2] ? open[1] > close[1] ? close > open ? close >= open[1] ? close[1] >= open ? close - open > open[1] - close[1] ? color.blue : na : na : na : na : na : na : na
barcolor(threeengulfing_mode ? Bueng2 : na)

// bearish engulfing (Beeng)
Beeng2 = open[3] < close[3] ? open[2] < close[2] ? close[1] > open[1] ? open > close ? open >= close[1] ? open[1] >= close ? open - close > close[1] - open[1] ? color.white : na : na : na : na : na : na : na
barcolor(threeengulfing_mode ? Beeng2 : na)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
alertcondition(shortbool and threeengulfing_mode and Beeng, title='Short Signal', message= 'Short Signal')        
alertcondition(longbool and threeengulfing_mode and Bueng , title='Long Signal', message= 'Long Signal')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `plotshape()` condition and `alertcondition()` conditions are different.

These are your `plotshape()` conditions:

`threeengulfing_mode and Bueng` and `threeengulfing_mode and Beeng`.

These are your `alertcondition()` conditions:

`shortbool and threeengulfing_mode and Beeng` and `longbool and threeengulfing_mode and Bueng`.

For debugging purposes, you can do:

```
bgcolor(longbool and threeengulfing_mode and Bueng ? color.green : na)
bgcolor(shortbool and threeengulfing_mode and Beeng ? color.red : na)
```

And look for green or red background on your chart. I haven't seen any. So, it is safe to assume that you alert conditions are not working as you expected.